# Which project files contain information that this is a maven project

Tags: spring, maven

There is a project on Spring. If I clone it from GitHub, then open it in IDEA, then it understands that this is a maven project, i.e. it highlights all the project folders with the right color - java, resources, etc. And if I just copy the source files of the project to another directory with all the folders, then IDEA does not perceive it as a maven project, but simply as a set of folders.
But on Github I don't see any other files except the source. And then where is all this information about the structure of the project stored?

That is, what files do I still need to copy so that the IDE recreates the entire folder structure as in the original project?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if it is a maven project, we use a `pom.xml` file. In case of gradle, we use `build.gradle` file.

Whenever a spring project is build, it reads one these files to get all dependancies.

Comment: File pom.xml there is, but for some reason IDEA did not perceive this project as maven, but simply as a set of folders.

Comment: Check if structure is such

```
-- .mvn
-- src
-- mvnw
-- mvnw.cmd
-- pom.xml
```

Comment: Folders and files .mvc, mvvm, mvw.cmd I did not copy, only pom.xml

Comment: In Idea, close the current project, then open a file and select the pom. Idea will import the project from it.